# Topics are empty when using the Debezium PostgresSQL Connector

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Currently, I am running Kafka and Debezium PostgreSQL Connector on Windows.

the steps I have followed:

Running Zookeeper:

```
 .\kafka\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\kafka\config\zookeeper.properties
```

Running Kafka:

```
.\kafka\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\kafka\config\server.properties
```

Running Connector:

```
.\kafka\bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat .\kafka\config\connect-standalone.properties
```

Sending Config.json file:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/ -d @.\kafka\config\config.json
```

Config.Json file is:

```
{
  "name": "my-postgres-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "localhost",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "database.password": "1524",
    "database.dbname": "MartenDB",
    "database.server.name": "postgres",
    "table.include.list": "public.student",
    "topic.prefix": "fulfillment",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "slot.name": "debezium"
  }
}
```

It's also showing this log in the connector cmd tab when I insert new data into the student table, but when I check the topic, it shows nothing. Can anyone help me here?
BTW, I have put all my Debezium PosgresSQL jar files into the Kafka/libs folder.

```
[2023-07-25 11:29:29,090] INFO [my-postgres-connector|task-0] 25 records sent during previous 00:01:49.859, last recorded offset of {server=fulfillment} partition is {transaction_id=null, lsn_proc=32329872, messageType=INSERT, lsn=32329872, txId=915, ts_usec=1690264768290221} (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:211)
```

Comment: Hi Sidhant, what is the topic you're checking? Based on the config file it should be `fulfillment.public.student` can you confirm the topic exists?

Comment: @Ftisiot Yes, it exists, but it doesn't show anything when I insert new data into the table.

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't add unrelated jdbc drivers to kafka classpath lib folder. Connect classpath should be separated from the broker (and Zookeeper)

Comment: Have you tried enabling debug logs in the log4j file? Or what is reported in /status API endpoint?